# referring json response and json object

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, object

i have the below response from server:

`{"result":{"js":"memo","text":"some value","tag":"some tag"}}`

in the client side (using jquery), i am parsing this as below:

`var obj = JSON.parse(resp);`

i have a variable defined as below:

`var prop = $(this).attr('pId');` -> **returns "text"**

i am looking for something like using this variable prop with the json object as follow:

`obj.result.prop` : obj.result.text = **i am expecting "some value" to be obtained**

is there a specific way to get a value like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
var prop = 'text';
console.log(obj.result[prop]); // prints "some value"
// equivalent to
console.log(obj.result.text);
```